# navigator.onLine is always FALSE when testing with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

In the app I'm testing with CasperJS we are checking if `navigator.onLine` is false to deactivate some parts of the app when there is no internet connection. The problem is that `navigator.onLine` seems to **always** be false when testing with CasperJS. I want `navigator.onLine` to be true when I'm actually on-line.

I've added a test in `casper.start(url, function(){...}` that checks the value of `navigator.onLine` and it always results in 'OFF LINE' message:

```
this.evaluateOrDie(function() {
    return navigator.onLine;
}, 'OFF LINE');
```

I searched for options that control this behaviour and only found `localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled`. I've set it to `true` but it didn't help.

There is no way to override value of `navigator.onLine` either.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a PhantomJS [bug](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10647). Thankfully, it looks like you can override whole `navigator` object to bypass this bug:

```
this.evaluateOrDie(function() {
    var fakeNavigator = {};
    for (var i in navigator) {
        fakeNavigator[i] = navigator[i];
    }
    fakeNavigator.onLine = true;
    navigator = fakeNavigator;

    return window.navigator.onLine;
}, 'OFF LINE');
```